# Должен, должна или должно?

Tags: орфография, склонение, род

Какой вариант будет в приложении?

Должен, должна, должно. Описать правописание:

> Где долж… находиться губка?

Comment: А с каким еще словом, кроме губки женского рода, здесь возможно согласование?

Comment: Если "губка" с большой, то "должен".